# QUERY error for BY column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, worksheet-function

I'm using the following query to pull data from one sheet into another.

```
=query(data!B2:CL,"select B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, BB, BZ, CA, BA where J = 'Industry Certification'",false)
```

The above query works perfectly. However, if I change 'BB' to 'BY'. I get the following error.

> Error
>
> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
>   PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "BY" at line 1, column 35. Was expecting one
>   of: "true" ... "false" ... "date" ... "timeofday" ... "datetime" ...
>   "timestamp" ... "min" ... "max" ... "avg" ... "count" ... "sum" ...
>   "no_values" ... "no_format" ... "is" ... "null" ... "year" ... "month"
>   ... "day" ... "hour" ... "minute" ... "second" ... "millisecond" ...
>   "with" ... "contains" ... "starts" ... "ends" ... "matches" ... "like"
>   ... "now" ... "dateDiff" ... "quarter" ... "lower" ... "upper" ...
>   "dayOfWeek" ... "toDate" ...  ...  ...
>    ...  ...  ... "(" ... "-"
>   ...

The value of cell 'BY' is a simple string (activities).

I'm scratching my head confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

According [to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#reserved-words), `BY` is a reserved word, to use it as an [identifier](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Identifiers), it should be back-quoted.

## Explanation

I think that it's a reserved word because it's used by two clauses:

- [Order By](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#order-by)
- [Group By](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#group-by)

Comment: I don't get the error when backquoted, but I also don't get the data from column `BY`.  The rest of the QUERY data does appear. Any suggestions for getting the data from `BY` to appear?

Answer (score 2):

## use `` ` `` instead of `'` like:

```
=QUERY(data!B2:CL, "select B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, `BY`, BZ, CA, BA 
                    where J = 'Industry Certification'", 0)
```

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

Although the [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124212/173960) provided by user0 is the best solution for this, I also wanted to add an alternative workaround for this.

You can use an **Array Formula** to duplicate the entire "BY" column in a different column and use that duplicated column in the Query formula. Check out the [following G-Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bb0Dy9Z-7G-8HOmW6tHXDh4xwreUQqFCKf2hQWhyt6k/edit?usp=sharing) which shows how this workaround can be implemented (it also has the solution)

Screenshot from the [G-Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bb0Dy9Z-7G-8HOmW6tHXDh4xwreUQqFCKf2hQWhyt6k/edit?usp=sharing) below:

[image: Workaround and Solution for "BY" column issue in QUERY formula]